# Create a file version.js when lerna release a new version

Tags: npm, lerna

We use lerna for releasing npm packages.

I would like to get the package version in the code. As I have gone through some of the articles it is not a good practice to do that. Also we use the same package in both front-end and back-end.

So I wanted to create a version.js and keep the current version during the release process. Is that possible in a lerna release process?

Comment: it's not very clear what you are asking and trying to achieve, perhaps this upcoming feature (merged but not yet released) might help? [feat(version): add json option to version command](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/pull/3858), if that is not helpful then please add more details to your question, it's very unclear as it is